# Inserting sound on Xcode 6 Swift

Tags: audio, swift

Could someone please help and tell me what the code would be to insert sound into my xcode 6 swift project and have it playing in the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OS X, to get sounds to play you can either use [NSSound](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or for more advanced things [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html).

With NSSound (the easiest way) you would put a sound file in your assets library, and then do:

```
var sound = NSSound(named: "name_of_sound")
sound.play()
```

For iOS try the following code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound_name", ofType: "wav"))
    println(alertSound)

    // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
    }

}
```

and it seems to be a good idea in general to have the audio player as a class member

Comment: it doesn't work, I get the error -  missing argument for parameter 'size' in call for the first line of code and for the second I get the error - expected declaration

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code - it should work perfectly I have used it a lot.  What file format is your sound, and where have you put it in your project?  e.g. if you have a wav sound 'alrighty.wav' you add the file to your project and then use the code var sound = NSSound(named: "alrighty.wav")

Comment: I am using a .wav file format and I have put into my project but I still get the same error, don't I need to import any module like i have done import SpirteKit but dont I need to import any audio module

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot to mention that. I've just tried the code you gave me but now I get the error - 'GameScene.Type' does not have member named 'sound'

Comment: and i also get the error- expected declaration  for the 3 line of code

Comment: The code is correct, it's probably where you've put it... Here is a more extensive answer which might help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386766/ios-sound-not-playing-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: If I was to put the code i have atm into the question could be able to tell me where to put it please, I'm sorry I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: Don't worry, a better snippet is now in the question, so hopefully it will be clearer.  You can add this as a view controller, and it will work...

Comment: All the code seems to be fine expect for the override func viewDidLoad() { because it give me the error - invalid redeclaration of 'viewdidload()'

Comment: James can you please help?

Comment: Keep trying it is correct!!  Start a new project and add this view and see that it works plus please accept the answer!