# Swift playing sound doesn't seem to work on my app

Tags: swift, avfoundation

Iv'e tried using the [SwiftySound](https://github.com/adamcichy/SwiftySound) lib 
but from some reason it didn't work, Iv'e also tried to play a sound using the AVFoundation but it doesn't seems to work neither (it's wether I get a nil on the url or it's simply doesn't work). the device is not muted and the speakers works fine, does anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are adding your sound files to your project and also to your application target. It may be the case that, `AVfoundation` or `SwiftySound` not able to find your sound file. Also check out example project of `SwiftySound`.

`pod try SwiftySound`

Also check out other similar questions:- [iOS Sound not playing in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386766/ios-sound-not-playing-in-swift?rq=1)

Comment: i did check the example of the SwiftySound and it worked fine, Iv'e also checked for application target and it seems fine, what do you mean by "pod try SwiftySound"

Comment: To try any pod you can use `pod try PODNAME`. And I was asking, if you have your sound files included in your target. Check Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle resources, and make sure your sound files are listed there.

Comment: you got it thanks! it wasn't on my bundle resources.. Iv'e been trying to fix it for the last 3 hours thank you!